# QML: Reading a buffer operated on by a compute shader

Tags: c++, opengl, qml, glsl, compute-shader

I have a compute shader operating on my buffer in my QML (5.8) app, the problem is that I cannot seem to read this buffer, only write to it.

My buffer is a `Qt3DRender::QBuffer`, I set its contents with

```
Qt3DRender::QBuffer::setData(QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(points_.linearize()), static_cast<int>(sizeof(PointType) * pc)));
```

where `pc` is the number of points.

To use it, I created a `QGeometry` which sets up `QAttribute`s, and apply the computer shader as a material component to the `Entity`

My material:

```
Material {
    property PointBuffer dataBuffer;

    ShaderProgram {
        id: computeShader
        computeShaderCode:  loadSource("qrc:/shaders/pointcloud.comp")
    }

    effect: Effect {
        techniques: [
            Technique {
                renderPasses: [
                    RenderPass {
                        shaderProgram: computeShader
                        parameters: [
                            // Point buffer
                            Parameter { name: "Particles"; value: dataBuffer }
                        ]
                    }
                ] // renderpasses
                filterKeys: [
                    FilterKey { name: "type"; value: "compute" }
                ]
                graphicsApiFilter {
                    api: GraphicsApiFilter.OpenGL
                    profile: GraphicsApiFilter.CoreProfile
                    majorVersion: 4
                    minorVersion: 3
                }
            } // technique
        ] // techniques
    }
}
```

In my buffer code though, whenever I read from the buffer (`Qt3DRender::buffer::data()`), I only get the data I wrote to it, not the result of the compute shader.

I've tried setting the `usage` to various things, but no dice.

In my OpenGL book, I see that one can `glMapBuffer` to have read/write access, and there's even a `QOpenGLBuffer` that has an ENUM to set the access in a similar way, but I can't seem to make use of either of these; *i.e.* I can't find a way to map my buffer, and the `QOpenGLBuffer` doesn't seem compatible with any of the renderers.

Comment: Though I haven't been able to get this working I received an [answer on the Qt Interest mailing list](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2017-March/026278.html) that states in Qt 5.9, there will be a `BufferCapture` component that is able to read in an OpenGL buffer.  I however found a different way (using a scene graph similar to the Squickle example) to get direct access to my OpenGL buffer

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to use `BufferCapture`, a feature added in 5.9 (who's alpha was only released this month.)

I haven't been able to try this solution yet, and will update this answer when I do.

There is an example of this in `qt5/qt3d/tests/manual/buffercapture-qml`

[Info Source: Qt Interest Mailing List](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2017-March/026278.html)

For a pre-5.9 solution, I re-wrote everything to be similar to the Squircle SceneGraph example, where I use "*raw*" OpenGL calls to draw what I need.  One huge advantage of this is that since I can append to an `QOpenGLBuffer`, I don't even need to read the buffer anymore.